# Android 4.4.2 webview scroll text issue

Tags: android, webview, scroll, titanium

When I scroll inside a webview, the text literally trips. It only happends when using Android 4.2.2 (API 19). I also use Titanium, maybe this is related to that, I dont know.

Screenshot:

[image]

Anyone knows whats going on here?

Comment: Have you tried in a physical android device? Webview's are finicky in the emulator

Comment: @JosiahHester Yeah, I first noticed it on a physical device (Samsung Galaxy S4, 4.2.2). The simulator behaves exactly the same as on the device.